# How to get discounted tickets to Epcot orlando

Tags: florida, disney, orlando, universal-studios

How can I get discounted tickets for Epcot in Orlando? How about Universal Studio?

Comment: I only know that Florida residents get cheaper rates for Disney tickets. I also think if you buy multiple day tickets for Disney, they can be bought at a discounted rate.

Comment: @pnuts - Why is asking about getting better prices at a tourist destination off topic?

Comment: @pnuts - Asking about purchasing a ticket for a tourist destination is not anywhere related to asking the price of cabbage. But I guess based on your logic, we should eliminate every question about discounted train tickets, airline tickets, etc (and there are a few).  Or are you simply one of those who feel that Disney is too childish for travel aficionados.

Comment: @pnuts - a quick search showed two questions here about buying camping gas, so .....

Answer (score 4):

Discounted tickets are sold by AAA to members.  I am not sure if you have to buy them from a Florida AAA office or if you can buy them from your local AAA office.

There are "tourist centers" selling discounted tickets, though the discounts are pretty negligible.  Any big discount should be viewed warily, as it likely has strings attached (limited hours of use, gotta go to a timeshare sales session, etc).

Multi-day ticket packages are available, that trim the cost per day.

There are resident discounts for Floridians, but these can not be scammed by out of staters, as everyone has to show proof of residency (DL, etc) the first time they enter Disney/Universal to validate their ticket(s) or season pass.